# How to specify alphabetical order of accented characters in Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

In Finnish the alphabetical order is abc...xyzåäö. In German, the order is [aä]bc...n[oö]p...xyz.

It seems that when Drupal views are sorted alphabetically, they follow the German order. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the view configuration is an SQL request to the database, so the sorting is done not in the View, Drupal or PHP code, but in the database. You need to make sure you have the collation correctly configured there for the views to return the result sorted the way you need it.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick: http://www.phoca.cz/download/category/17-phoca-changing-collation-tool